# Problem allocating derived class array with new

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator, derived-class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a simple program

```
$ cat a.cpp 
#include <iostream>
class MyClass {
    public:
        virtual void check() {
            std::cout << "Inside MyClass\n";
        }
};

class MyClass2: public MyClass {
    public:
        int* a;
        virtual void check() {
            std::cout << "Inside MyClass2\n";
        }
};

int main() {
    MyClass *w, *v;
    w = new MyClass2[2];
    v = new MyClass2;
    std::cout << "Calling w[0].check\n"; w[0].check();
    std::cout << "Calling v->check\n"; v->check();
    std::cout << "Calling w[1].check\n"; w[1].check();
}
$ g++ a.cpp
$ ./a.out 
Calling w[0].check
Inside MyClass2
Calling v->check
Inside MyClass2
Calling w[1].check
Segmentation fault
```

I thought it is possible to use new to allocate derived class objects. Also, v->check() seems to work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
w = new MyClass2[2];
```

This creates an array of two `MyClass2` objects.  It is of type `MyClass2[2]`.  The new expression returns a pointer to the initial element of this array and you assign that pointer to `w`.

```
w[1].check();
```

This treats `w` as a pointer to an array of `MyClass` objects, *not* as an array of `MyClass2` objects.

You cannot treat an array of derived class objects as if it were an array of base class objects.  If you want to be able to use the derived-class objects, you need an array of pointers:

```
MyClass** w = new MyClass*[2];
w[0] = new MyClass2;
w[1] = new MyClass2;
```

Comment: ( (MyClass2*) &w[1])->check() also gives segmentation fault.

Comment: That's correct, of course. In order to get the desired behavior, `w` would need to be an array of pointers or references to the base class.

Comment: I think you meant `MyClass** w = new MyClass*[2];`. Right?

Comment: @Nawaz:  /facepalm.  Thanks; fixed.

Comment: @highBandWidth:  You would need to use `static_cast<MyClass2*>(w)[1].check()`

Answer (score 2):

As an extension of @James McNellis and @Nawaz proposed solutions (which are correct), you can avoid a lot of confusion by using container classes you have available to you and smart pointers.  Namely `std::vector` and `std::array` (depending on your compiler version, this may be in the `tr1` namespace or you may need to download the boost library to use it) and `shared_ptr` (there are others you could choose from as well, though).

Comment: Good call. As it stands, all versions of this code leak memory. Smart pointers would help avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Since James appears to be disappear, I think I should post the correct solution:

```
MyClass** w = new MyClass*[2]; //Note the difference from James solution!
w[0] = new MyClass2;
w[1] = new MyClass2;

std::cout << "Calling w[0].check\n"; w[0].check();
std::cout << "Calling w[1].check\n"; w[1].check();
```

This should work!

Comment: I was hungry and left for lunch.

Comment: @James: I knew you were busy somewhere. So thought to correct that typo. Hope you didn't mind. :-)