# Array memory Allocation doesn't work

Tags: c++, memory-management, polymorphism, pointer-arithmetic

I have the next classes:

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
  int num;
};
```

in my main I have:

```
int main() {
    A* vec; // A is a class with pure virtual functions
    vec = new B[2]; // want to create a vector of B
}
```

vec[0] is defined correctly, but vec[1] is NULL. why didn't it allocate me a fit memory?

I don't want to change the lines of the main. just make it working.

(I know I can change the main into: B* vec = new B[2] but I don't want)

any help appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973221/problem-allocating-derived-class-array-with-new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot treat arrays polymorphically, the C++ language does not support it. The expression `vec[x]` uses pointer arithmetic to determine the location of the element. If you are accessing it through a base class pointer it will not work if the size of the objects vary in any way.

For example, you have base class that is 4 bytes in size and the subclass is 8 bytes in size.

```
base *a = new child[4];
```

When you access `a[1]` the compiler calculates the offset using the size of the base class. In this case the offset is 4 bytes which ends up pointing to the middle of the first element.

I recommend using a `std::vector` or `std::array` of pointers with an appropriate smart pointer.

```
// For arrays that needs to be resized (requires delete for each new)
std::vector<A*> vec(5, NULL);
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = new B();
}

// for arrays that are fixed in size (requires delete for each new)
std::array<A*, 5> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i] = new B();
}

// for arrays that are fixed in size with smart pointers
// no delete needed 
std::array<std::unique_ptr<A>, 5> vec;
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    vec[i].reset(new B());
}
```

Comment: can't you just do B* vec_cp = new B[2]; memcpy(vec, vec_cp, sizeof(vec_cp)) ? By operating directly on the memory, you can bypass this limitation IMO.

Comment: Just because the objects exist in memory correctly does not mean that the pointer arithmetic will work out.  The vec pointer in this case will still be broken and vec[2] will still point to one byte later in memory, rather than the appropriate 8 bytes later to boint to the second B object.

Comment: @georgesl `B` can be implicitly converted to `A` so your memcpy does the same thing as plain old assignment. You still end up with the same issue.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, thank you! for the code of: A vec*[5] = new B*[5]; it will allocate me a matrix of 1*5, right?

Comment: @AlonShmiel Yes, the number inside of the brackets specifies the number of elements to allocate. In this case it's an array of 5 pointers to type an object of type `A`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, not sure what you intended to do with the last bit of code but that is not valid C++ code.

Comment: @RSahu Thank you very much! That was just bad and so had to go away. I blame the bartender ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you would like it to be polymorphic just create an array of pointers

`new A*[array_size]`

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet illustrates the problem you are having.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A {
};

class B : public A {
  int num;
};

int main() {
    A* vec; // A is a class with pure virtual functions
    vec = new B[2]; // want to create a vector of B

    cout << sizeof(vec) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(*vec) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(vec[2]) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(new B()) << endl;
}
```

In pointer arrithmetic, the size of the type of the pointer you allocated is what is used for incrementing, not the size of the true type of the object it is pointing to.  More simply, the language does not support polymorphic arrays.  This is simply an explanation of why.