# What is the meaning of `A vec*[5] = new B*[5]`

Tags: c++

[Array memory Allocation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589430/array-memory-allocation-doesnt-work)

I saw the following code and found that it doesn't compile.
Is the code in the OP correct?

Thank you

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
  int num;
};

int main() {
  /* Original Post
     error: expected initializer before ‘*’ token
     A vec*[5] = new B*[5];

  A vec*[5] = new B*[5];         // <<< I don't understand this line
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      vec[i] = new B();
  } 
  */

  // My modified version
  A* vec[5];
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      vec[i] = new B();
  }  

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe in some language, not in C++.

Comment: The code in the question you referenced is `A* vec; vec = new B[2];`. Did you mean to reference a different question?

Comment: Last solution posed by Captain Obvlious

Comment: @q0987, that snippet of code has been removed. It is not valid code. It shouldn't have been there.